# gdb parses stream as argument

Tags: macos, gdb, macos-sierra

When executing `./foo 0 1 2 > out.txt` arguments 0, 1 and 2 are passed to `foo` and stdout is streamed to out.txt.

When running in gdb: `run 0 1 2 > out.txt` everything is passed to `foo` as arguments, including ">" and "out.txt".

AFAIK, the shell used by gdb is /bin/bash, gdb version 7.10 (from brew). Running MacOS Sierra (10.12.2). Runs correctly on El Capitan (10.11.6) and whatever Linux we tried.

Edit: This happens on El Capitan if I add `set startup-with-shell off`. Setting to `on` works fine on El Capitan, but causes `During startup program terminated with signal ?, Unknown signal.` on Sierra.